# Automatically add my logo in products images

Tags: image, product-images, image-upload

is there a way to add automatically my logo in the bottom right(whatever) position of my product images?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [using product image watermarks](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/using-product-image-watermarks)

1. From the Admin panel, select System > Configuration.
2. In the Configuration panel on the left, under General, select Design.
3. Click to expand the Product Image Watermarks section

[image]